# Is there a parametric trend test with provable power?

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, nonparametric

I have $N$ samples $x_1,\dots,x_N$ and I want to test following hypotheses.

The null hypothesis is that $x_1,\dots,x_N$ i.i.d. sample from a normal poplulation $N(\mu_1,\sigma^2)$, with unknown mean $\mu_1$ and known variance $\sigma^2$. The alternative hypothesis is that the joint distribution of $x_1,\dots,x_N$ is an $N$-dimensional normal distribution $N(\vec{\mu}_2,\Sigma)$. The mean vector has the form $(a,\dots,a) + (\beta(1),\beta(2),\dots,\beta(N))$ with unknown $a$ and know $\beta(x)$. The covariance matrix $\Sigma$ is known. Further more, the function $\beta$ is an increasing function on $x$.

I want to test these hypotheses with provable power, so I need to take a test and give a lower bound on the power of the test rather than just estimates the power of the test by Monte-Carlo simulation. But I don't know how to do it. Would you please give me some reference on the subject?

Comment: You say $\Sigma$ is known.  For a power calculation you need $\vec{\mu}_2$ too, which involves knowing $a$ and even then it may not be tractable

Comment: @Henry Thanks for your kindly comment. I guess maybe there is a test with a lower bound on the power determined by the $\beta$ term, since the $\beta$ term is the only source of the trend. For example, by take $x_2-x_1,x_3-x_2,\dots,x_n - x_{n-1}$ I can ignore $a$.